# NoSuchElement exception error in particular program

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

I have used Scanner for all my programming needs, but for some reason, I'm unable to get through this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException   at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)     at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)  at
>   Main.main(Main.java:9)

In the following code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int T = in.nextInt();
        if(T>0&&T<Math.pow(10,5))
        {
            String ans[]=new String[T];
            int a=0;
            int C=0,D=0,L=0;            
            for(a=0;a<T;a++)
            {
                C=in.nextInt();
                D=in.nextInt();
                L=in.nextInt();
                if(L>(C*4)+(D*4)||L<(C/D)*4+(C%D)*4||L%4!=0)
                ans[a]="no";
                else
                ans[a]="yes";
            }
            a=0;
            while(a<T)
            {
                System.out.println(ans[a]);
                a++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have gone through all the questions regarding the said error, but am not able to solve my problem. I have also tried inserting `in.hasNextInt()` too, but the error persists.

Comment: You tried inserting it *where*?

Comment: your code is running perfectly in my netbeans.

Comment: You need to provide more explanation. What input produces this exception ? What is your desired output ?

Comment: Well, this is the error that would occur if you call `nextInt`, and the input is exhausted.  I.e. there's **no such element**.  Your input must have 3T integers after reading T. It probably doesn't. It would also be very easy to add a `println` or two to determine how far it's getting. Programmer heal thy self.

Comment: The program is for a competitive programming contest. I'm only dependent on an example input they're providing to check my program. I have no clue what kind of input they're giving, but my BlueJ shows me the correct information for each input I give, at least.

Answer (score -1):

"Thrown by the nextElement method of an Enumeration to indicate that there are no more elements in the enumeration." - from JDK7 doc. 
"Thrown by various accessor methods to indicate that the element being requested does not exist." - from JDK8 doc ( [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) ).
For me, this code is working fine.